# Securing Model-Bound Laravel Forms

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form using model-binding to enter data into a database. I'm trying to serve it over https but can't figure it out.

Here's the view:

```
    {!! Form::model(new App\MissingHours, ['route' => ['missinghours.store'], 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
        @include('missinghours/_form', ['submit_text' => 'Submit Hours'])
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I've tried setting the url to https://appurl/missinghours/store but that clearly didn't work. I also tried model_secure taking after Form::open_secure, and that didn't work. When I serve the page over https and try to submit the form, I get a warning about it being un-secure and the data is not submitted.

Controller:

```
 $input = Input::all();
 $save = MissingHours::create( $input );
```

Comment: That's probably because you don't have SSL certificate set up in your server.

Comment: It's on heroku and there is a valid SSL cert. The page itself loads via https and the lock icon shows in browswers and you can verify the certificate, it's just the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your whole site to be https - including forms, you can Insert the following codes below `RewriteEngine On` on your `public/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

**EDIT:**

You can create a `before` middleware like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class BeforeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->secure()) return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then use that middleware in your form.

More on Laravel Middlewares [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware).

Comment: Yes, I could use .htaccess, but I was looking for the Laravel solution to secure forms, not the entire site.

Comment: I added another possible solution with the use of a `Middleware`.